# compare to next row group data.frame - count per group

Tags: r, compare, match

I am pretty new to R and I have the following problem that I try to solve.

I would like to count the amount of times that **a** (*just one*) wet day follows up a dry day per month - averaged for all the years. The data is stored in a data.frame. OR to put it simple:
I want to count the amount of times that the following row (x+1) has a value > 0 if the row x has a value of zero for a group(Month) - averaged for all years.

I first thought that I could try it the same way as was done in the stackoverflow forum with question **compare to next row group data.table**. Unfortunatelly I got the error:

```
 Error in `[.data.frame`(weatherdata, , `:=`(PCPnextdat, PCP[match(Date +  : unused argument (by = Month)
```

when executing the following task:

```
 weatherdata[, PCPnextdat := PCP[match(Date + 1, Date)] , by=Month]
```

The important columns in the datafile, lets call it **weatherdata** have the following structure, and are data for 36 years - from 01Jan1979 to 31July2014:

```
 Date Year Month Day PCP
1979-01-01 1979 01 01 0.000
1979-01-02 1979 01 02 0.987   <---- FIRST DAY
1979-01-03 1979 01 03 0.876
1979-01-04 1979 01 04 0.000
1979-01-05 1979 01 05 0.234   <---- SECOND DAY
1979-01-06 1979 01 06 0.000
1979-01-07 1979 01 07 0.123   <----- THIRD DAY
1979-01-08 1979 01 08 1.899
```

So in this example the amount of wet days that follow up dry days is 3 days.

I allready found a way to make a new colum with the precipitation data (x+1).
By using:

```
 weatherdataPCP.next <- weatherdata..5341$PCP[c(2:12986,1)]
```

This would give:

```
Date Year Month Day PCP PCP.next
1979-01-01 1979 01 01 0.000 0.987 <--- ONE
1979-01-02 1979 01 02 0.987 0.876
1979-01-03 1979 01 03 0.876 0.000
1979-01-04 1979 01 04 0.000 0.234 <--- TWO
1979-01-05 1979 01 05 0.234 0.000
1979-01-06 1979 01 06 0.000 0.123 <--- THIRD
1979-01-07 1979 01 07 0.123 1.899
1979-01-08 1979 01 08 1.899 0.000
```

What I would like to end up with is:

```
Month dry.wet.p.month
01 9.23
02 12.14
03 9.51
04 8.71
05 13.11
06 9.09
07 6.55
08 7.22
09 10.67
10 4.23
11 5.67
12 7.54
```

All help/tips/tricks are appreciated :) !

Comment: Is it not 5 days? First 0 with 2 non zeros, then 2nd zero with 1 non zero, then 3rd zero with 2 non zero.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I am going to rephrase a little bit. It is the amount of times **A** wet day followed a dry day. Thats also why I gave the example ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a data.table option of what I think you're looking for. First, aggregate the number of wet/dry combinations per Month *and* Year. Then, compute the mean of that sum only per Month.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)

dt[, list(drywetpermonth = sum(PCP > 0 & shift(PCP == 0), na.rm = TRUE)), 
     by = list(Year, Month)][
   , list(drywetpermonth = mean(drywetpermonth)), by = Month]
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! However it is not what I am looking for or I might be executing it wrongly. I get a new column **drywetpermonth** with either N/A or 133 or 134 for all of the 12987 rows.
I just need an average of the amount of wet days that follow up dry days per month. So I would like a new data.table or vector with just twelve rows for drywethpermonth. The outcomes of this column should always lie between 0 and 16. Since you cannot have more than 16 times a wet day following up a dry day per month. Thus the new table would look like the one given in the example.

Comment: `sum(..., na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: @T.BruceLee you asked for a `sum` per month, didn't you? Now if you need an average, just use `mean` instead of `sum`

Comment: @docendodiscimus I tried it with mean. But I got the error:

          

            Error in `[.data.table`(weatherdata, , `:=`(drywetpermonth, mean(PCP >  :   Type of RHS ('double') must match LHS ('integer'). To check and coerce would impact performance too much for the fastest cases. Either change the type of the target column, or coerce the RHS of := yourself (e.g. by using 1L instead of 1)

Comment: @T.BruceLee, run this first: `dt[, drywetpermonth := NULL]` and then try again

Comment: @T.BruceLee, I added another option - perhaps that's what you want..?

Comment: Plus one for you (though you were a bit hard on me few hours earlier ) :-)

Comment: @docendodiscimus . I adjusted the question a little bit about 10 min ago. I did ask for a sum per month but averaged over the years. So for example in year one: 7 times a drywet day in April. Year two: 11 times a drywet day in April. Year three: 8 times a drywet day in April. This would give as average for april 26 / 3 = 8.67

Comment: @T.BruceLee, in that case, my last update should be what you want. Take a look (it aggregates per month and year first, and then computes the mean of those sums per month)

Comment: @docendodiscimus. It is exactly what I wanted. I adjusted the formula a bit. Because it counted the amount of times a dry day followed a wet day.
Thanks for helping out! I wish I could give you more than just +1

Comment: @T.BruceLee if you are happy with the solution, you can accept it (or wait a bit longer if you want other answers)